# Check with PHP if mysql InnoDB settings is one file per table

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

Is there a way to check with PHP if the configuration of MySQL is set so InnoDB stores each table in one extra file?

If i call

```
show variables like 'innodb_file_per_table'
```

this is set to `ON`

Is this the only thing I have to check to be sure, that I don't get such an unwantad several GB `ibdata1` file?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but you could always use ENGINE=InnoDB when you create a new table

Comment: sure, I use `ENGINE=InnoDB`. that is the question, I want to be sure, that id doesn't add the new table to the same `ibdata1` file